# How do I real-time synchronize two files in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, sync

I'd like to sync two files in real-time in Windows 8.1.
For example let us say:
A: PathFileA
B: PathFileB

Any modification in A or B keep them having the same version real-time. Is that possible?

I have tried DSynchronize or FreeFileSync but they seem to work only with directories and moreover the real-time of DSynchronize looks like not working.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: How about creating a hardlink using `mklink /H`? That way you don't have to synchronize anything. Both path's point to the same file, you can't get more real-time than that.

Comment: Is this simply to have the file available on two separate paths? or to keep a backup that is up to date after every edit?

Comment: I'd like to have two Word files, one in OneDrive and one in Google Drive because I have all my stuff in Google Drive but I want to be able to edit the file with the Word app on my tablet and so I need it also in OneDrive. This is the reason for the necessity of a syncronization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a hardlink to the file, that way you don't have to synchronize anything. Both path's point to the same file, you can't get more real-time than that.

[See TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx)

```
mklink /H
```

**Edit**

The original file is still present after creating a hardlink

[image]

Comment: I have noticed that after creating an hard link my original file disappears. Why is this happening?

Comment: I have no idea. When I test, the Original file doesn't disappear *(see edit)*

Comment: Could it be because they are one on google drive and one on OneDrive? They are two word files to be syncronized and edited from PC and tablet (with the word app, this is because I need it on onedrive too)

Comment: "When in doubt, run procmon". *(Sysinterals)*. This would be my first step to try. Have your document on google drive *(local I assume?)*. Start procmon *(have advanced output enabled), create the hardlink and verify what happened to the original file by dissecting the log.